# On the Wii Virtual Console version of The Legend of Zelda, how can you save a game in progress?

Tags: nintendo-wii, virtual-console, the-legend-of-zelda

In the original *Legend of Zelda* for the NES, there was a trick where you could (if I remember correctly) press <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>select</kbd> simultaneously on the 2nd controller to bring up the `Save` dialog.

After buying the Wii Virtual Console version, I tried this trick and it didn't work.

Is there a way to save your game in-progress on the Wii version? (maybe I'm missing something obvious, like generic save state functionality)

Comment: If you pushed reset & the power button at the same time, that would  prevent losing your progress.

Comment: "In the original *Legend of Zelda* for the NES, there was a trick where you could" hold the A button and press up.  (Not the Select button.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Commonly with virtual console games, you can hit the center button (Wii menu?), and exit the game.  This will automatically save the state of the game.  Next time the game loads you'll begin at that spot; however, after reloading once the save state is no longer available -- resetting the system won't allow you to resume from that state again.

Comment: +1. This is true of all of the virtual console games, as far as I know. This is possible because they're all emulated, and so it's easy to just write the state of the simulator to disk.

Comment: +1, great to know. This will be useful if I'm in the depths of a dungeon and don't want to completely reset. I'll probably use a combination of my approach and yours.

Comment: There is a problem with using this method in Legend of Zelda. Sure you save the game in the spot-but you miss the warp back to the start of a dungeon or the starting screen on the overworld. CyberSkull's method is better for the original style save.

Answer (score 19):

Figured it out. It was actually in the manual. (who would have thought to look there?) ;-)

You hit <kbd>+</kbd> (start) to bring up your inventory, then <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> (select) at the same time. All on the first controller. Done!

Comment: You also have the opportunity to save when you die. Since you always start in the same place when you load a game, there's no difference between the two ways of saving except convenience.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie — At the time, many considered it a point of pride to complete the game with their death counter still at 0.  Thus, a *significant* difference between "save while alive" and "save after dying".  ;-)

Comment: @Ben A fair point. :)